# Let $(X, \tau)$ be a compact space and $(X, \tau')$ a Hausdorff space such that $\tau' \subset \tau$. Show that $\tau'=\tau$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a compact space and $(X, \tau')$ a Hausdorff space such that $\tau' \subset \tau$. Show that $\tau'=\tau$.

Since the identity map $id:(X, \tau) \to (X, \tau')$ is a continuous bijection it's a homeomorphism between the spaces.

So if $O \in \tau$, then $O= id^{-1}(U)$ for $U \in \tau'$. But $id^{-1}(U)=U$ so $O=U$.

Is the proof really this simple or am I skipping some steps?

Comment: Not all identity maps are continuous (or have continuous inverses)—otherwise this proof would show that every two topologies are the same! Are you using the compactness assumption somehow?

Comment: @GregMartin: Compact domain+continuous implies a closed map.  The inverse of a closed bijection is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the proof looks correct but you should be careful with the explanations.

Indeed, the identity you wrote is continuous (by the inclusion of topologies) and bijective (obvious) but this is not enough to get an homeomorphism.
This last property follows from the fact that a continuos map from a compact to an Hausdorff space is closed.

Finally if the identity is an homeomorphism then it's open, hence for every $O\in\tau$ you have $\tau(O)\in\tau'$ and then $\tau\subseteq \tau'$ giving $\tau=\tau'$.